# Following HQL doesn't work (Records within date range)

Tags: hibernate

I would like to fetch records between two dates. The query below is not working. Tried the following:

```
1. from Employee where emp_Gkey=121 and empCreated BETWEEN '2016-08-29 
   00:00:00.0' and '2016-09-02 00:00:0.0';
2. from Employee where emp_Gkey=121 having empCreated BETWEEN '2016-08-29
   00:00:00.0' and '2016-09-02 00:00:0.0';
3. from Employee where emp_Gkey=121 and empCreated >= '2016-08-29
   00:00:00.0' and empCreated <= '2016-09-02 00:00:0.0';
```

Please kindly help. I am using an Oracle Database and the hibernate column type is defined as "timestamp".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In HQL queries, the parameters need to be the same type/class as the mapped property in the entity.

You need something like this:

```
final TypedQuery<Employee> query =
     em.createQuery("select e from Employee e where e.empCreated BETWEEN :from AND :to");
query.setParameter("from", new Date());
query.setParameter("to", new Date());
```

Given that the type of the empCreated variable is `Date`.

I'm using standard JPA here (JPQL), I'll leave it up to you to convert the method calls to whatever you are using..

In general, when writing HQL/JPQL queries, you have to forget how your database looks. The queries are against entities (java classes), not the database tables!